# Can't control volume using PHP exec command and NirCmd

Tags: php

I'm running wampserver 2.2 on Windows 7, and I'm trying to use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to mute windows volume.
My code is:

```
<?php
exec("c:\nircmd\nircmdc mutesysvolume 1");
?>
```

The command seems to work well, and mute my sound when run not via PHP, but doesn't work through PHP.

Help anyone? Or any other suggestions on how to make a remote control using PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence `\n` inside a double-quoted string resolves to a newline character, destroying your path.

You can use single quotes instead:

```
exec('c:\nircmd\nircmdc mutesysvolume 1');
```

Or, even better, use forward slashes instead of backslashes to avoid the problem entirely:

```
exec('c:/nircmd/nircmdc mutesysvolume 1');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use double quoted string do it like ( and try .exe ). Or like "Jon" said use forward slashes.

```
exec("c:\\nircmd\\nircmdc.exe mutesysvolume 1");
```